# How to install Mac OS X upon NTFS partition with Win XP on it?

Tags: macos

My original Mac Mini hard drive is waste, so, i've replaced it with an old hard drive with XP installed on it. Actually, computer starts correctly, and Windows XP is loaded. Now I want to format this hard drive using Mac FileSystem and install Mac OS X on it.

Actually I have Mac Tiger DVD in front of me (DVD was sale to me with computer) but when I insert the disc in optical drive under Windows XP it tries to read than spit it off (i've tried with MS Office CD and it works).

The question is simple: what can I do to install Mac OS X if disk is NTFS partition and Win XP is installed?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

It's ok, welcome to the dark side.  In answer to the issue...

You can also start by inserting the Install DVD and restarting your computer while holding down the <kbd>C</kbd> key

Windows cannot read the disk format but the Mac can.

These instructions are for Leopard but they haven't changed

[Apple Support Installing Leopard from DVD](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1544)

edit: forgot to add, Choose 'Erase and Install'

Comment: Same behaviour. Alternative?

Comment: Get a new OSX install disk, it's busted. Depending on how old the mac mini is, you should be good to install up to Snow Leopard.  If you have the model number of the mac, we can be more definite.

Comment: I've changed the install disc but problems are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding the 'option' key to have your Mac present you with some boot options.

It should then read the CD/DVD and allow you to boot from that.  Once you've booted the DVD you should quite easily be able to figure out how to erase the NTFS partition (if you choose to do so) and replace it with an HFS+ partition, and install OS X onto that.

Comment: "Windows" is the one and only alternative shown.

Comment: @Mariano - then you have a problem with the CD/DVD, or perhaps a hardware issue with your CD/DVD drive.

Comment: I've changed the install disc but problems are still there.

Comment: @Mariano then presumably, the problem isn't in the media but in the hardware.  Get an external CD/DVD drive and try that, with the now known-good installation media.

Answer (score 0):

**You will have to reformat the disk in Disk Utility first.** You can find Disk Utility in the Utilities menu on the Mac OS X Install DVD. Boot to this by restarting your Mac and holding the <kbd>C</kbd> key until you see the installer window.

1. Open Disk Utility and find the internal hard drive.
2. Select the Partition tab
3. Change the Partition layout to 1 partition
4. Click Options
5. Select GUID Partition Table if your Mac has an Intel processor (I'm guessing it does if you can boot to Windows) or Apple Partition Map if your Mac has a PowerPC processor.
6. Name the partition Macintosh HD
7. Click Apply
8. Quit Disk Utility and install Mac OS X normally.

Good luck!

Comment: Nothin happen holding C? Where is the error?

Comment: Try resetting the PRAM. Hold down Command + Option + P + R on startup until you hear two chimes, then hold C until you get to the installer. DON'T let go until you get to the installer.

Comment: Can you rephrase that?

Comment: I've tried to reset the PRAM, but nothing happen' when I press the C key (as you explained above), the install disc is spitting out and Windows XP will be started.